# Tangent vectors as directional derivatives on manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I'm reading Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists by Chris J Isham. On page 75 of the book, the author says:

A tangent vector $v \in T_p M$ can be used as a "directional derivative" on functions on $M$ by defining: $$v(f) := \frac{df(\sigma(t))}{dt} \Big|_{t=0}$$

where $v = [\sigma]$ is the equivalence class of the vector $v$ (all curves tangent at $p$). Coming from multivariable calculus, I am struggling to understand the motivation behind this definition. What is the reasoning and motivation behind this definition? And how does this relate to the concept of tangent vectors and tangent planes in ordinary vector calculus?

Comment: Do you consider submanifolds $M \subset \mathbb R^N$ or "abstract" manifolds given by a smooth atlas?

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm considering manifolds in the abstract sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things simple, let's stick to $3$-dimensions, so it is like familiar "ordinary vector calculus".

If $\sigma(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ is a curve, then its tangent vector is $\sigma'(t) = (x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))$. Let $p=\sigma(0)$, and $v = \sigma'(0)$.

By the chain rule from "ordinary vector calculus", the right-hand side of the equation you give above is:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} f(\sigma(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} $$
and then of course evaluate at $t=0$. The left-most term in my equation above, $\left. \frac{d}{dt}f(\sigma(t)) \right|_{t=0}$, is by assumption the vector $v$ acting on the function $f$. On the other hand, the right-most part of my equation above looks like a dot product:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} = \nabla f \cdot \sigma' $$

This is also the "ordinary vector calculus" definition of the directional derivative in the direction $v$:

$$ D_v f(p) = \nabla f(p) \cdot v $$

Comment: But wasn't $v = \sigma '(0)$ defined to the $\left. \frac{d}{dt}\sigma(t) \right|_{t=0}$ so why is it equal to $\left. \frac{d}{dt}f(\sigma(t)) \right|_{t=0}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, $v = \sigma'(0)$. It was a typo on my part. I should have said that $\frac{d}{dt}f(\sigma(t))|_{t=0}$ is by assumption $v(f)$. I changed my answer to word that sentence more correctly.